# How reliable is the randomness of the shuf command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, random-number-generator

I ran the following command to generate 1 billion random numbers:

```
time shuf -i 1-1000000000 > "SHUF TEST 1"
```

To my surprise it was able to do this in less than 10 mins. I then ran the output file through `uniq -d` to determine how many of the generated numbers were duplicate, and was again surprised when it turned out to be 0. I also ran the output file through `uniq -u` and `sort -u` to confirm these results.

How is it that the `shuf` command is able to generate a billion random numbers in such a relatively short amount of time, and can I depend on its randomness? Note that I don't need a cryptographically secure random number generator for my needs, just something good enough to always return a unique number.

Comment: `to determine how many of the generated numbers were duplicate, and was again surprised when it turned out to be 0` – `shuf` does not generate random numbers, it generates random *permutation*, random order. With `-i 1-1000000000` one should expect each integer from this range to appear exactly once. No surprise at all.

Comment: As @KamilMaciorowski states, a "shuffling" algorithm creates an array of number 1 to *n*, then randomly switches pairs of numbers. Does it matter if the order is exactly duplicated each time it's run? Some algorithms start the random number generator at the same pint each time.

Comment: That makes sense now. Either one of you should feel free to add an answer along those lines.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody mentioned the `-r` option. If it is given, `shuf` will generate random numbers; from 1 to 1000000000 inclusive in this case. There is also the `--random-source` option.

Comment: "Careful, `shuf` is not cryptographically safe by default! You need to pass `--random-source=/dev/urandom` to get a proper RNG." https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14846285

Comment: "The `shuf`, `shred`, and `sort` commands sometimes need random data to do their work. For example, `sort -R` must choose a hash function at random, and it needs random data to make this selection. By default, these commands use an internal pseudo-random generator initialized by a small amount of entropy, but can be directed to use an external source with the `--random-source=file` option." https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shuf` utility shuffles its input by outputting a random permutation of its input lines. According to it's manpage, "Each output permutation is equally likely". An analogy would be to shuffle a deck of cards.

If the input lines contain duplicates, the output from `shuf` will also contain duplicates. Why?  Because `shuf` performs a random permutation of it's input.  If the input lines contain no duplicates, the output from `shuf` will contain no duplicates.

In your example, `shuf -i 1-1000000000`, the `-i` option causes `shuf` to act as if it's input came from a file containing the range of unsigned decimal integers 1 through 1000000000, one unsigned integer per line. In other words, `shuf` acts as if it had 1000000000 lines of input with each line containing a unique unsigned integer. Hence there are no duplicates to be found in the output.